# Problema con el height reajustable y el scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una página web que se conecta con una API que devuelve ciertos datos. Antes de llegar esos datos, la página tiene un alto automático y al llegar los datos y construir unas tablas para mostrar los datos tiene otro alto, pero la página no reajusta el alto, por lo que el scroll vertical queda acortado y no se muestran todos los datos que necesito. Una cosa que no entiendo es que al ocurrir un evento que modifique el tamaño del viewport o de la visualización de la página en sí (abrir el inspector, hacer zoom, quitar zoom, recargar la página, etc.) la página si reajusta el alto. No muestro mucho código porque no sabría que mostrar, pero estoy a disposición de añadir a la pregunta los datos que sean necesarios. Muchas gracias!

Este es el scroll de la página después de crear los datos por primera vez:
[image]

Este es el scroll de la página después de recargar la página o hacer zoom o lo que sea:
[image]

Un tipo de tabla(una de varias):

```
<div class="hide" id="mostrarNotasMedioTrimestral">
      <h1> NOTAS</h1>
      <!-- Primer trimestre -->
      <h2> Primer Trimestre</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive">
           <table class="table table-striped  no-more-tables " id="tablaPrimerTrimestreM">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th>Espacio Curricular</th>
                 <th>1° Calif.</th>
                 <th>2° Calif.</th>
                 <th>3° Calif.</th>
                 <th>4° Calif.</th>
                 <th>5° Calif.</th>
                 <th>Integración</th>
                 <th>Conducta</th>
                 <th>Promedio</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
         </table>
       </div>
       <!-- Segundo trimestre -->
       <h2> Segundo Trimestre</h2>
       <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-striped no-more-tables" id="tablaSegundoTrimestreM">
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Espacio Curricular</th>
                <th>1° Calif.</th>
                <th>2° Calif.</th>
                <th>3° Calif.</th>
                <th>4° Calif.</th>
                <th>5° Calif.</th>
                <th>Integración</th>
                <th>Conducta</th>
                <th>Promedio</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Tercer trimestre -->
    <h2> Tercer Trimestre</h2>
    <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table table-striped no-more-tables" id="tablaTercerTrimestreM">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Espacio Curricular</th>
             <th>1° Calif.</th>
             <th>2° Calif.</th>
             <th>3° Calif.</th>
             <th>4° Calif.</th>
             <th>5° Calif.</th>
             <th>Integración</th>
             <th>Conducta</th>
             <th>Promedio</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Código JS que genera la tabla:

```
var mostrarNotasMedioTrimestral = function (datos) {
        var data1
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            data1 += '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].nombre + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_1 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_3 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_4 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_5 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e1_6 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].conduc_1 + '</td>' +
                // '<td>' + datos[i].conduc_1 + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }
        $("#tablaPrimerTrimestreM").append(data1);

        var data2
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            data2 += '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].nombre + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_1 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_3 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_4 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_5 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e2_6 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].conduc_2 + '</td>' +
                // '<td>' + datos[i].conduc_2 + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }
        $("#tablaSegundoTrimestreM").append(data2);
        var data3
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            data3 += '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].nombre + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_1 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_3 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_4 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_5 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].e3_6 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + datos[i].conduc_3 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + promedio(datos[i], 3) + '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }
        $("#tablaTercerTrimestreM").append(data3);
        $("#mostrarNotasMedioTrimestral").removeClass('hide');
    };
```

Comment: Y el código, y las fotos... o evidencia. No podemos adivinar como lo estas haciendo o que intentas lograr..

Comment: Hola @David081 ya agregué más o menos lo que pediste, espero te sirva, sino decime y agrego más de lo que pueda

Comment: para poder visualizar el overflow-y del contenenor padre no deberia estar en hide, es lo mas que se me ocurre viendo tan poca informacion, es problema de CSS claro esta

Comment: Hola @John ya agregué el código javascript de la tabla, se te ocurre algo?

Comment: se me ocurre que pegues el código fuente generado de la pagina para ver mejor, insisto el problema es el CSS no el JS

Comment: @John como sería? No termino de entender